# Synonym request: "euler-phi" as a synonym for "totient-function"

Tags: support, tag-management

I just encountered [a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/107476/43351) involving the Euler phi, or totient function $\phi(n) = \#\{1 \le m \le n: \gcd(m,n)=1\}$.

Apparently, the tag associated to this is [totient-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/totient-function). However, I have always had the impression that a large fraction of the mathematical populace refers to this function by name of "Euler phi".

It therefore makes sense to make [euler-phi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-phi) or [euler-phi-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euler-phi-function) a synonym of [totient-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/totient-function); I prefer the former as it's shorter.

I'm posting this request here because I "need a score of 5 or more in the tag to propose a synonym". Posting this request is in accordance with Jeff Atwood's answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3519/43351).

Comment: In the future, though, we do have [a nice big thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363) for synonym proposals...

Comment: @Ｊ.M. Which I had seen, but it appeared to me as if it concerns only tags that already exist, i.e. merge proposals. It might be an idea to rephrase the question body to explicitly welcome situations such as this one. (I myself have taken the remark on board.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done, as this is one of the least ambiguous cases of a synonym that I've seen. (I chose the latter option, since I believe it is better to be more descriptive, and we have auto-complete for tags so typing is not an issue.)

Comment: Yes, I figured that it would be approved. Thanks. :)